# Event that triggers only once after an order is placed successfully

Tags: magento

i have a requirement that after an order is being placed successfully i need to change the status of order to my custom status,i have used sales_order_place_after event,but i dont get any order status information while using that observer and if i use sales_order_save_after every time an order is saved my code will execute ,i want my code to execute only when order is placed successfully and saved in database , Is there any event that triggers only once after an order is placed.Please let me know.

Comment: Did you try `sales_order_payment_place_end`

Comment: Or you can check the order status https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/order-status.html to prevent unnecessary triggers.